# How to call a post web service with UrlSession.DataTaskPublisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a simple question that I can see only `dataTaskPublisher` in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) with which I was able to call a get web service but how can I call a post web service which can return a publisher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can define a request and call it in your `dataTaskPublisher` like this :

```swift
var request =  URLRequest(url: URL(string: "url")!)
let session = URLSession.shared
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.HTTPBody = try! JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: [])
session.dataTaskPublisher(for: request)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use constructor with `URLRequest` and prepare request with any HTTP method you need.

> ```
> /// Returns a publisher that wraps a URL session data task for a given URL request.
> ///
> /// The publisher publishes data when the task completes, or terminates if the task fails with an error.
> /// - Parameter request: The URL request for which to create a data task.
> /// - Returns: A publisher that wraps a data task for the URL request.
> public func dataTaskPublisher(for request: URLRequest) -> URLSession.DataTaskPublisher
> ```